# Is it possible to insert an HBox between a AdvancedDataGrid Header and the the grid data/content?

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, advanceddatagrid

I need to insert a Box containing some text that appears between the grid header and main content and spans all the grid columns. I've been searching and experimenting (addChildAt()) but no luck so far. Is this possible to achieve?
If not, is it possible to dynamically render the text in the header itself, below and spanning the column header text?
Any advice would be great,
Thanks
Brian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to do this is to extend the AdvancedDataGrid to change the layout logic for the header, columns, and cell renderers to allow for space for your new component.

It will not be a trivial undertaking; but should be doable.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'll have a go at it